# Not every node is calculated by tensorflow.keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I run this source code.

It calculates 60000 train data and 10000 test data

I suppose it should be calculated 60000 times for each epoch,like this below

```
x_train shape: (60000, 28, 28, 1)
y_train shape: (60000,)
60000 train samples
10000 test samples
60000/60000 [==============================]
.
.
.
```

However,in fact the result is like this below

```
x_train shape: (60000, 28, 28, 1)
y_train shape: (60000,)
60000 train samples
10000 test samples
469/469 [==============================] - 32s 69ms/step - loss: 2.2910 - accuracy: 0.1347 - val_loss: 2.2686 - val_accuracy: 0.3145
Test loss: 2.2686383724212646
Test accuracy: 0.31450000405311584
elapsed time:34.918644189834595
```

Why only 469 times calculated???
Where  is  wrong??

Python 3.8.5
tensorflow             2.3.1

```
    import tensorflow
    import tensorflow.keras as myKeras
    from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
    from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
    from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

    start = time.time()
    batch_size = 128
    num_classes = 10
    epochs = 1
    img_rows, img_cols = 28, 28
    # the data, split between train and test sets
    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
  
    if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
        x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
        x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
        input_shape = (1, img_rows, img_cols)
    else:
        x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
        x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
        input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
    x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
    x_train /= 255
    x_test /= 255
    print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
    print('y_train shape:', y_train.shape)
    print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
    print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')
 
    y_train = myKeras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
    y_test = myKeras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                    activation='relu',
                    input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss=myKeras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
                optimizer=myKeras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
                metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(x_train, y_train,
            batch_size=batch_size,
            epochs=epochs,
            verbose=1,
            validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
    score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
    print('Test loss:', score[0])
    print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
    elapsed_time = time.time() - start
    print("elapsed time:{0}".format(elapsed_time))
```

Comment: 469 is number of steps per epoch,since you have a batch size of 128 and number of samples 60000, it need at least 469 steps to go through all the data samples,the data is trained batch by batch, like 469*128 = 60032 close to 60000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the steps_per_epochs and validation_steps parameters correctly in the model.fit() functions.

**steps_per_epoch** the number of batch iterations before a training epoch is considered finished. If you have a training set of the fixed size you can ignore it but it may be useful if you have a huge data set or if you are generating random data augmentations on the fly, i.e. if your training set has a (generated) infinite size. If you have the time to go through your whole training data set I recommend skipping this parameter.
validation_steps similar to steps_per_epoch but on the validation data set instead of the training data. If you have the time to go through your whole validation data set I recommend skipping this parameter.

**validation_steps** similar to steps_per_epoch but on the validation data set instead of on the training data. If you have the time to go through your whole validation data set I recommend skipping this parameter.

**In your case set:**

1. batch_size = 200
2. steps_per_epoch = 300
3. validation_steps = 50

Comment: Thank you very much! it works!. I suppose it shows the number of data `60000/60000 [==============================] `  but it shows the `300/300 [==============================] ` the number of batch. That's ok though, does it depends on tensorflow version??

Comment: Now you are using a batch generator, it means your data is divided into batches. And every batch contains 200 images. So 300*200=60000, this is how it works.

Comment: It's completely version-independent.

Comment: I see, I am trying Keras with plaidML as well. `model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                batch_size=200,
                epochs=epochs,
                verbose=1,
                validation_data=(x_test, y_test))` it works without `steps_per_epoch` and sam batch_size but it shows `60000/60000`

Comment: If you don't set steps_per_epoch, it will run but will train whole data(60000) in one epoch. So you set this parameter.

Comment: When I set `steps_per_epoch=300`  shows error `If steps_per_epoch is set, the \`batch_size\` must be None`

Comment: It's ok if you don't set the batch_size, sometimes it automatically divides it.

Comment: Thank you for your help and explanation. I need to learn a bit more.